# Turn off other CSS Sheets when printing

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to turn off certain CSS sheets when printing?

For example, assume I have three CSS Sheets.

When a user is printing I would like to turn off bootstrap.css & overrides.css. I've tried using

```
<link href "bootstrap.css" media="print not" />
<link href "overrides.css" media="print not" />
<link href "print.css" media="print" />
```

I would like to avoid overriding all the CSS attributes in the print CSS. I considered using JavaScript to add and remove the CSS style sheets but I'm being told there isn't a beforePrint event in all browsers.

Comment: Couldn't you set  the media attribute to screen instead of print for those that you don't want printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need "not print" instead of "print not"

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries or https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: It's typically recommended that you just edit your post instead of deleting it and posting another one.